# Ask MongoDB host if it is Master using Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, master-slave

Is it possible to ask a MongoDB host if it is the master using the Java drivers?

I've checked the issue [Ask MongoDB if it is Master out of a bashscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814031/ask-mongodb-if-it-is-master-out-of-a-bashscript) but I'd rather try to do this in my application rather than wiring in a bash script.

Comment: You can just do that but in Java using the: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/isMaster/ command

Comment: I want to use the Java drivers :)

Comment: Yeah, and database commands are callable from the Java Driver, they are just different to find, try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394917/how-to-execute-mongo-admin-command-from-java

Comment: Nice! Copy paste that as a response and I'll approve it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is no helper function provided for the Java Driver, but still, you can issue commands with the driver.

If you go into the MongoDB Shell, and print

`db.isMaster` (without the parenthesis)

and hit enter, the JavaScript interpreter will print out the implementation of the helper function. On `db` context, the `isMaster()` function is a helper, with the following code:

`function () { return this.runCommand("isMaster"); }`

So in the background `db.runCommand("isMaster")` performed. There are a lot of helpers in the Mongo Shell, some of them are fairly complicated and simplifies your everyday work on administration.

You can do the same in the Java Driver with the following method on an object of class `DB`:

`CommandResult  command(DBObject cmd, int options, ReadPreference readPrefs, DBEncoder encoder)`
*Executes a database command.*

`CommandResult  command(String cmd, int options)`
*Executes a database command.*

So there is no need to construct a `DBObject` for the command, just pass the string: `"isMaster"`. Anticipate a `CommandResult` object and proceed as you will.